# Explicit creation of objects with a trivial default constructor using placement-new in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, malloc, placement-new

My understanding is that the rules about [implicit creation of implicit-lifetime objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Object_creation) applies only to C++20 and newer. I'm stuck with C++17, so I wondered if I could fix [this example code](https://oleksandrkvl.github.io/2021/04/02/cpp-20-overview.html#fix-impl-creation) (so that it is not UB in C++17) by adding a placement-new expression that doesn't initialize the object, like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

struct X { int a, b; };

// I believe writing to the fields of the returned object is UB in C++17, OK in C++20 and later.
X* make_uninitialized_x() {
    auto p = (X*)std::malloc(sizeof(X));
    return p;
}

// Is writing to the fields of the returned object OK in C++17 and earlier?
X* make_uninitialized_x_fixed_for_cpp17() {
    auto p = (X*)std::malloc(sizeof(X));
    new (p) X;  // This gets optimized away with -O1 flag
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Yes, placement new is the way to create an object in a storage location.

Comment: Yes, until C++20 `malloc` did not start object's lifetime, but `new` does.

Comment: I wonder if [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) is required, as you return `p` and not directly `new (p) X`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point, it might be.  Another option would be to use `return new (p) X;` which should probably also fix that potential issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: According to the comments, either one of the fixed functions below would be OK in C++17 and earlier.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

struct X { int a, b; };

X* make_uninitialized_x_fixed_v1() {
    auto p = (X*)std::malloc(sizeof(X));
    new (p) X;
    return std::launder(p);
}

X* make_uninitialized_x_fixed_v2() {
    auto p = (X*)std::malloc(sizeof(X));
    return new (p) X;
}
```